# Updating Cells in Google Sheets by latest Timestamp input from Google Forms

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

**My Problem:**

I would like to make updating cells in google sheets based on the last input from a google form. Does somebody know a solution?

**What I tried:**

I made a query function that takes the form inputs and added a row next to the data that counts every input(=IF(B2="";"";1)than in the cell below(=IF(B3="";"";A2+1), so each new input has a higher value than the one bevor. Then I tried to write a function for a fixed cell that queries the inputs of the list in search for the highest value, but I can´t find a formula that worked.

Example:

[image: Exampe Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by `query()`

#### Formula:

`=ifna(query('Form Responses 1'!$A$2:$C,"select C where B = "&indirect(address(row(), 1, 4))&" order by A desc limit 1"), "")`

#### Note:

- Just copy the formula directly to the status column on sheets tab, no need to edit per cell
- It gets the last value of column C where column B is equal to the ID number of the row. Returns blank if ID number is not present.

#### Sample Data:

[image: sample]

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: thank you so much!!!! You are a great person!!!! I want to thank you for you effort and the time you put it in it!!! You are really awsome!!!! This helped me a lot! I wasn´t able to find a solution. BIG THANKS

Comment: You are welcome @Proboto, Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I have to write again! This made me so happy that you helped me! Thank you very much!